# Append struct to anonymous slice of structs in Go

Tags: go, struct, slice

I'm working with a defined struct such as this one:

```
type MyList struct {
    Items  []struct {
        ResourceLocation string `json:"resourceLocation"`
        Resource         Tmp  `json:"resource"`
    } `json:"items"`
    ListOptions
}
```

and I need to add a struct to Items slice.

I tried the following:

```
tmp2 := struct {
            ResourceLocation string
            Resource         Tmp
        }{
            Resource:   myTempStruct,
        }

        tmpList.Items = append(MyList.Items, tmp)
```

but I'm getting a:

> Cannot use 'tmp' (type struct {...}) as type struct {...}

error.

By the way, I cannot modify

```
type MyList struct {
    Items  []struct {
        ResourceLocation string `json:"resourceLocation"`
        Resource         Tmp  `json:"resource"`
    } `json:"items"`
    ListOptions
}
```

that's the reason why I cannot assign a name to `Items` and define it in a separate struct.
Thanks.

Comment: You have to add the identical json tags as well to the anonymous struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the question does not work because field tags are part of the type.

Add the field tags to the anonymous type in the question:

```
item := struct {
    ResourceLocation string `json:"resourceLocation"`
    Resource         Tmp    `json:"resource"`
}{
    Resource: myTempStruct,
}
```

Better yet, declare a type with same underlying type as an element of MyList.Items.

```
type Item struct {
    ResourceLocation string `json:"resourceLocation"`
    Resource         Tmp    `json:"resource"`
}
```

Use that type when constructing the element:

```
item := Item{Resource: myTempStruct}
list.Items = append(list.Items, item)
```

Comment: that worked like charm. Didn't know the field tags had to do with that, I thought they were only like decorative (for information purposes only). Thanks